# How to draw TTreeView's styled selection rectangle during AdvancedCustomDrawItem?

Tags: delphi, treeview, selection, ownerdrawn

I'm doing custom `TTreeView` drawing from scratch using `OnAdvancedCustomDrawItem` event, and I wonder how to render these selection and hot rectangles correctly in the background of my owner-draw items? They are Vista/7 styled so I cannot simply fill the background in some solid color.

[image]

I tried to draw my items at `cdPostPaint` stage, but if I leave `DefaultDraw := True` at`cdPrePaint` stage to draw selection background, the complete default drawing occurs, including text of items.

```
procedure TForm1.TreeView1AdvancedCustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomTreeView;
  Node: TTreeNode; State: TCustomDrawState; Stage: TCustomDrawStage; var PaintImages,
  DefaultDraw: Boolean);
begin
  case Stage of
    cdPreErase:
    begin
      DefaultDraw := True;
    end;

    cdPostErase:
    begin
      DefaultDraw := True;
    end;

    cdPrePaint:
    begin
      // I thought this will paint only the selected/hot backgrounds, 
      // however this will paint whole item, including text.
      DefaultDraw := True;
    end;

    cdPostPaint:
    begin
      DefaultDraw := False;

      // painting my owner-draw text
      // .........
    end;
  end;

  PaintImages := False;
end;
```

Comment: You need to use the theme API, the single worst documented area of Windows. Good luck getting anywhere with that. Virtual Treeview is looking like a good option here. I guess that's easier to customise.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No chance to use standard TreeView's drawing?

Comment: Of course. But without documentation, it's not easy.

Comment: DrawThemeBackground is the API you need. But custom drawing themed common controls is tricky. I'd definitely look at the Virtual Treeview source code for some clues.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is my solution (tested).

Note the TreeView must have `HotTrack := True` to draw hot items normally.

There also must be additional drawing when themes not enabled.

```
uses
  UxTheme,
  Themes;

const
  TreeExpanderSpacing = 6;

procedure TForm1.DrawExpander(ACanvas: TCanvas; ATextRect: TRect; AExpanded: Boolean;
  AHot: Boolean);
var
  ExpanderRect: TRect;
  Graphics: IGPGraphics;
  Points: array of TGPPoint;
  Brush: IGPBrush;
  Pen: IGPPen;
  ThemeData: HTHEME;
  ElementPart: Integer;
  ElementState: Integer;
  ExpanderSize: TSize;
  UnthemedColor: TColor;
begin
  if ThemeServices.ThemesEnabled then
  begin
    if AHot then
      ElementPart := TVP_HOTGLYPH
    else
      ElementPart := TVP_GLYPH;

    if AExpanded then
      ElementState := GLPS_OPENED
    else
      ElementState := GLPS_CLOSED;

    ThemeData := OpenThemeData(TreeView1.Handle, VSCLASS_TREEVIEW);
    GetThemePartSize(ThemeData, ACanvas.Handle, ElementPart, ElementState, nil,
      TS_TRUE, ExpanderSize);
    ExpanderRect.Left := ATextRect.Left - TreeExpanderSpacing - ExpanderSize.cx;
    ExpanderRect.Right := ExpanderRect.Left + ExpanderSize.cx;
    ExpanderRect.Top := ATextRect.Top + (ATextRect.Bottom - ATextRect.Top - ExpanderSize.cy) div 2;
    ExpanderRect.Bottom := ExpanderRect.Top + ExpanderSize.cy;
    DrawThemeBackground(ThemeData, ACanvas.Handle, ElementPart, ElementState, ExpanderRect, nil);
    CloseThemeData(ThemeData);
  end
  else
  begin

    // Drawing expander without themes enabled

    Graphics := TGPGraphics.Create(ACanvas.Handle);
    Graphics.SmoothingMode := SmoothingModeHighQuality;

    ExpanderRect := ATextRect;
    ExpanderRect.Right := ATextRect.Left - TDPIAware.GetScaledSize(TreeExpanderSpacing96dpi);
    ExpanderRect.Left := ATextRect.Left - TDPIAware.GetScaledSize(TreeExpanderSpacing96dpi) -
      TDPIAware.GetScaledSize(Max(TreeExpanderCollapsedWidth96dpi, TreeExpanderExpandedWidth96dpi));

    if ASelected then
      UnthemedColor := ColorToRGB(clHighlightText)
    else
      if AExpanded then
        UnthemedColor := clBlack
      else
        UnthemedColor := clGray;

    SetLength(Points, 3);
    if AExpanded then
    begin
      Points[0] := TGPPoint.Create(ExpanderRect.Right, ExpanderRect.Top +
        (ExpanderRect.Bottom - ExpanderRect.Top - TreeExpanderExpandedHeight96dpi) div 2);
      Points[1] := TGPPoint.Create(ExpanderRect.Right, ExpanderRect.Top +
        (ExpanderRect.Bottom - ExpanderRect.Top + TreeExpanderExpandedHeight96dpi) div 2);
      Points[2] := TGPPoint.Create(ExpanderRect.Right - TreeExpanderExpandedWidth96dpi,
        ExpanderRect.Top + (ExpanderRect.Bottom - ExpanderRect.Top +
        TreeExpanderExpandedHeight96dpi) div 2);
      Brush := TGPSolidBrush.Create(TGPColor.CreateFromColorRef(UnthemedColor));
      Graphics.FillPolygon(Brush, Points);
    end
    else
    begin
      Points[0] := TGPPoint.Create(ExpanderRect.Right - TreeExpanderCollapsedWidth96dpi,
        ExpanderRect.Top + (ExpanderRect.Bottom - ExpanderRect.Top -
        TreeExpanderCollapsedHeight96dpi) div 2);
      Points[1] := TGPPoint.Create(ExpanderRect.Right,
        ExpanderRect.Top + (ExpanderRect.Bottom - ExpanderRect.Top) div 2);
      Points[2] := TGPPoint.Create(ExpanderRect.Right - TreeExpanderCollapsedWidth96dpi,
        ExpanderRect.Top + (ExpanderRect.Bottom - ExpanderRect.Top +
        TreeExpanderCollapsedHeight96dpi) div 2);
      Pen := TGPPen.Create(TGPColor.CreateFromColorRef(UnthemedColor));
      Graphics.DrawPolygon(Pen, Points);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.TreeView1AdvancedCustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomTreeView;
  Node: TTreeNode; State: TCustomDrawState; Stage: TCustomDrawStage; var PaintImages,
  DefaultDraw: Boolean);
var
  NodeRect: TRect;
  NodeTextRect: TRect;
  Text: string;
  ThemeData: HTHEME;
  TreeItemState: Integer;
begin
  if Stage = cdPrePaint then
  begin
    NodeRect := Node.DisplayRect(False);
    NodeTextRect := Node.DisplayRect(True);

    // Drawing background
    if (cdsSelected in State) and Sender.Focused then
      TreeItemState := TREIS_SELECTED
    else
      if (cdsSelected in State) and (cdsHot in State) then
        TreeItemState := TREIS_HOTSELECTED
      else
        if cdsSelected in State then
          TreeItemState := TREIS_SELECTEDNOTFOCUS
        else
          if cdsHot in State then
            TreeItemState := TREIS_HOT
          else
            TreeItemState := TREEITEMStateFiller0;

    if TreeItemState <> TREEITEMStateFiller0 then
    begin
      ThemeData := OpenThemeData(Sender.Handle, VSCLASS_TREEVIEW);
      DrawThemeBackground(ThemeData, Sender.Canvas.Handle, TVP_TREEITEM, TreeItemState,
        NodeRect, nil);
      CloseThemeData(ThemeData);
    end;

    // Drawing expander
    if Node.HasChildren then
      DrawExpander(Sender.Canvas, NodeTextRect, Node.Expanded, cdsHot in State);

    // Drawing main text
    SetBkMode(Sender.Canvas.Handle, TRANSPARENT);
    SetTextColor(Sender.Canvas.Handle, clBlue);

    Text := Node.Text;
    Sender.Canvas.TextRect(NodeTextRect, Text,
      [tfVerticalCenter, tfSingleLine, tfEndEllipsis, tfLeft]);

    // Some extended drawing...

  end;

  PaintImages := False;
  DefaultDraw := False;
end;
```

Comment: Nice. You may want to use some of the methods in Themes that wrap up the low level API. Save having to mess with theme handles.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan When I used `Themes` wrapper for drawing, it didn't draw the Vista-style expanders and gradient backgrounds, I dont' know why. Maybe they wanted to make `Themes` independent from Windows version so they use some compatible constants. I'll inspect the `Themes` code later.

Comment: If you could show the Drawing-expander-without-themes code that would be helpful for others who come along later and don't know how to do that.